# Appending different items to different keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have initialized a dictionary like so:

```
dic = {'A':[],'B':[],'C':[]}
```

My goal is to fill the dictionary by appending some values like so:

```
{'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 'B': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
 'C': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]}
```

The way I was able to do it is by using the following lines of code:

```
for j in range(0,10):
    dic['A'].append(j)
    dic['B'].append(j*2)
    dic['C'].append(j*3)
```

My goal is to do such procedure in a smart and more elegant way.
I would like this:

```
dic[['A','B','C']].append(j,j*2,j*3)
```

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

**Note**: my example could be misleading, I apologize. The reason why I append j, j*2 and j*3 is just for demonstrational purposes; the appended value could be very generic for example letters or other random numbers.

Comment: `(dic[x].append(j**i) for j in range(10) for i, x in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C']))` means you only have to range over `j` once

Comment: Can you give another example with letters?

Comment: Sure here it comes

Comment: I don't think there is going to be an answer that is as efficient AND as readable as what you already have.

Comment: You need to show the contents of `letters1` and `letters2`

Comment: sorry about the confusion :/

Comment: So no loop needed, just `dic['A'] = letters1` etc. ?

Comment: possibly I would like to have a compact way to append the elements at every iteration; the loop can remain as it is

Comment: `dic['A'],dic['B'],dic['C'] = letters1,letters2,[a+b for a,b in zip(letters1,letters2)]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will have the expected result:

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C']

print({
    key: range(0, 10 * i, i)
    for i, key in enumerate(keys, 1)
})
```

Result:

```
{
    'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    'C': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27], 
    'B': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
}
```

Comment: While you have answered the OP's question. I have to think this one falls under the category of explicit is better than implicit. Personally I think the op should stick with his solution. Kudos though on this, I couldn't think of anything.

Answer (score 3):

For achieving what you want, you may create a *dict comprehension* expression:

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C']

my_dict = {key: [j*i for j in range(10)] for i, key in enumerate(keys, 1)}
```

where `my_dict` will hold the value:

```
{
    'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    'B': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
    'C': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27], 
}
```